# GPU don't load correctly

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, gpu

I accidentally removed my GPU drivers from the computer, and then the GPU got some bugs: first he showed up some green stripes, then it went 640x480 resolution, and now it's loading the BIOS with a lot of white/green stripes and showing ONLY 16 colors. I've tried to load the driver again, but the driver won't load.

My GPU: Asus GT 9800

Drivers used - NVIDIA GeForce (used to work before)

Comment: That sounds more like the hardware has failed. You'll need to replace the card. Its pretty ancient and from a series of Nvidia cards that liked to burn themselves up so its not surprising that it would die.

Comment: If you need to merge accounts, [read this](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 2):

I have bad news for you - your GPU is probably fried.

Drivers only affect graphics cards when an operating system is loaded. BIOS, UEFI, other pieces of firmware and early boot stages of OS work in an ancient, universal graphics mode that doesn't require drivers. If anything is wrong on these screens, it usually indicates hardware failure.

Here's an example of picture generated by fried GPU: (it should be black and white only)

[image: Artifacts caused by a damaged GPU]

Other possible symptoms of GPU damage include inability to install proper drivers.

Try to borrow another GPU and see if it works properly. If it does, then you have to get a new one.

It's also possible that your CPU has integrated low-performance GPU, it should be enough for a quick test. Just remove the broken graphics card and connect monitor to your motherboard. If motherboard has no monitor outputs, then you don't have integrated GPU and have to borrow dedicated one.